How to use Lifecycle in Compose Multiplatform?
Recently, lifecycle library has been updated so it should be possible to use it in Compose Multiplatform.
The issue is that I can't get it to work. I try to add lifecycle observer, but when I try to debug, I don't get logs from oncreate, onresume etc. events.
Did someone manage to make it work?
LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
    when(event) {
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
            println("Hello from onresume")
        }
        else -> { println("Hello from ${event.name}")}
    }
}


I did the below as described in the docs and it worked as expected on Desktop.
Added these dependencies:
implementation("org.jetbrains.androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.8.1")
// To make coroutines and flows in lifecycles work correctly on desktop:
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-swing:1.8.1")

Then in my @Composable function:
val observer = remember {
    LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                println("Resumed")
            }

            else -> {
                println(event.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

OR
val currentState by LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle.currentStateFlow.collectAsState()
LaunchedEffect(currentState) {
    if (currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        println("RESUMED")
    } else {
        println(currentState.name)
    }
}

